# Is implementing Finite state machine a right way to do in crm?

Tags: design-patterns, state-machine

I was looking into the oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16754_01/doc.75/e16700/mng_service_life_cycles.htm#CJABIAEJ).

What one can get from it is they have developed it using FSM.
but my idea or confusion remains on the topic is how one can drive FSM without triggers/events for example consider a person doing recharge of mobile online.
The only trigger he gets is that recharge process initiated. Now the recharge journey needs to breaked in FSM. whatever the internals may be but how can I go from one state to another without another event.

Have any one implemented FSM in any crm, in between the long internal flows.
Is there any standard approch on same??

Answer (score 0):

This fsm is useful to animate GUI maybe it is a start:http://www.jsclasses.org/package/361-JavaScript-Animate-page-elements-using-Finite-State-Machines.html

Comment: no this is not related. I was asking about the long internal business logic